# How to force paginator length even when connected to a dataSource?

Tags: angular, pagination

I have a mat-table with a data source and I have created pagination for it which loads the next few entries every time you move to the next page.
My query returns the total amount of results so I want to always show the total amount on my paginator (1 out of x) instead of showing the total length of the dataSource as the maximum.

I know that when you set the dataSource.paginator = this.paginator it automatically does the connection but no piece of code I thought of could overwrite it.
I have tried linking the [length]="numberOfHits" but it doesn't take.

Also, I don't wish to handle the dataSource seperetaly (meaning I won't connect it to the paginator) because then the table lazy loads by adding more rows to it and not by switching the page to the next one.

.html:

```
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  *ngIf="!loadingData; else loading"
  class="row"
>
...
</table>

<mat-paginator
  #paginator
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="paginatorPageSizeOptions"
  [pageIndex]="currentPage"
  (page)="onPageChange($event)"
></mat-paginator>
```

.ts:

```
createTable() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

I expect the length property of the paginator to be overwritten when I type this.paginator = this.numberOfHits.

**EDIT:**
I have tried this already but no success:

```
  <mat-paginator
    #paginator
    [length]="numberOfHits"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="paginatorPageSizeOptions"
    [pageIndex]="currentPage"
    (page)="onPageChange($event)"
  ></mat-paginator>
```

It does work on first startup but once I switch the page to the next one it goes back to show the dataSource length.

Comment: in your html file: [length]="numberOfHits" and in ts where you assign the responste to dataSource.data add: this.numberOfHits = result.TotalAmount (your api response must have 2 parameters : Count and Rows, where Count is the total number of lines and Rows is the list of rows)

Comment: Tried it, sadly to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<mat-paginator
  #paginator
  [length]="totalRecords"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="paginatorPageSizeOptions"
  [pageIndex]="currentPage"
  (page)="onPageChange($event)"
></mat-paginator>
```

So by assigning total records you can make mat-paginator to show custom length.

In your case you can do like

```
<mat-paginator
  #paginator
  [length]="numberOfHits"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="paginatorPageSizeOptions"
  [pageIndex]="currentPage"
  (page)="onPageChange($event)"
></mat-paginator>
```

In case if you don't pass 'numberOfHits' value, it will automatically assign dataSource length to paginator.

In case above is not working, we can make it work, by adding

```
this.paginator.length = this.numberOfHits;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sadly, adding the [length] property doesn't take effect, it is still overwritten by the dataSource.

Comment: Tried that as well, no luck. No matter where in my code I try to update the paingaotr (Even through datasource.paginator) it doesn't take.

Comment: setTimeout(() => {
        this.paginator.length = this.totalRecords;
      });

Comment: @Soraky keeping the paginator.length in settimeout might work

Comment: It does work and thanks for that but it's still a workaround, I can even see the numbers flicker when it changes...

Comment: @Soraky did you by any chance find a solution for that workaround?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to pass the `[length]` property to the template, as you already did, and then in my TS class I added the following methods:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.dataSource) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.dataSource && this.dataSource.paginator && this.dataSource.paginator.length !== this.totalElements) {
    this.dataSource.paginator.length = this.totalElements;
  }
}
```

In your case you should replace `this.totalElements` with `this.numberOfHits`.

Unlike `ngAfterViewInit()`, `ngAfterViewChecked()` gets called after the `ngAfterViewInit()` and **every** subsequent `ngAfterContentChecked()` (so basically once for every change detection run).
The `if` inside `ngAfterViewChecked()` ensures that the heaviest part of the code inside it, in this case the assignment, only run if needed. This should improve performace, even if slightly, by avoiding useless assignments every change detection cycle.